# React UI - Get absolute path of file from File Browser

Tags: reactjs

Requirement:
To get the absolute path using a File browser but **do not upload the file**.

When tried to access the input path in Chrome, I am getting path as "C:\fakepath\filename.txt"

```
<input name="Path" type="file" id ="path" value={DiagPath} onChange={this.handlePathChange} />

handleSubmit = (url) => {axios.post(url,this.state,{ headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain" }})
 .then(res=>console.log(res);)
}
```

Is there any way to get the absolute path of file selected, as we don't need file to be uploaded.